# Dynamically created buttons within cells of a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a color swatch that can be used to select colors from.  My thought is to create a table, and have each cell of the table be a button from which the user can click to select the color they want to use.  Th this point I have not even tried to give my buttons any functionality until I can actually determine that they are generating I am simply trying to lay out the table at this point and test whether or not the buttons are appending to each cell.  This is the reason for the innerHTML = 'test'.  However nothing is appearing so I fear the buttons are not properly appending.  I am brand new to coding and would prefer to stick with vanilla JS for the time being.  Mahalo

```
// get reference for the pixelPainter div
let body = document.getElementById('pixelPainter');

//create the color swatch
let swatch = document.createElement('table');
swatch.id = 'swatch_base';

for (var i = 0; i<6; i++){
    let row = document.createElement('tr');

//create columns and attach buttons to each cell so that the buttons can be selected to choose a color
for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    let colorButton = document.createElement('button');
    colorButton.className('colorChoice');
    colorButton.innerHTML('test'); // just trying to test for button
    cell.appendChild(colorButton);
    row.appendChild(cell);
}
swatch.appendChild(row);
}

body.appendChild(swatch);
swatch.setAttribute('border', '1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/qnrra88L/

actually, `className` and `innerHTML` are not a functions, also className should be `classNames`

change these two lines

```
colorButton.className('colorChoice');
colorButton.innerHTML('test');
```

as

```
colorButton.classNames = 'colorChoice';
colorButton.innerHTML = 'test';
```

Comment: Such simple mistakes.  Thanks for your help.